# Regular expression prevent dash from being entered

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have the following regular expression within my .NET MVC file:

```
   [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{0,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Please
   enter a valid User Code.")]
```

I want the characters to be no longer than 10 characters. It should allow for alpha-numberic values only and prevent any spaces.

The code above works but the user is able to enter a dash "-". How do I prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `\-` from the character class `[]` and put `^` at the start of the pattern to assert start of string.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}$"
```

If you don't want to match an empty string, make it `{1,10}`.